# How to prove the inequality $\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{1-x^2}\ge \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$ when $xy+yz+zx=1$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification, contest-math

> Prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{1-x^2}\ge \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ where $xy+yz+zx=1$ and $0< x,y,z <1$

I have a proof :Let $2A,2B,2C$ be the angles of an acute angled triangle, also let $x=\tan A,y=\tan B,z=\tan C$ easy to check $0< x,y,z <1$.
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{cyc} \tan 2A \right)\ge \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Because in a triangle with angles $2A ,2B,2C$
$$\sum_{cyc} \tan 2A\ge 3\sqrt{3}$$

I am however looking for alternative proofs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2} \implies f''(x)=\frac{2x}{(x^2+3)}{(1-x^2)^3}>0, 0<x<1.$$
So by Jensen's Inequality if folloes that
$$\frac{f(x)+f(y)+f(z)}{3}\ge f\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right), 0<x,y,z<1.~~~~(1)$$
Also $$xy+yz+zx=1 \implies (x+y+z)^2 \ge 3~ \implies p \ge \sqrt{3}~~~(2)$$
From (1), we can write
$$F=\frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac{y}{1-y^2}+\frac{z}{1-z^2} \ge 3 \frac{p/3}{1-p^2/9}$$
From (2) $$ p \ge \sqrt{3} \implies p^2/9 \ge  1/3 \implies 1-p^2/9 \le 2/3 \implies \frac{1}{1-p^2/9}\ge \frac{3}{2} \implies \frac{p}{1-p^2/9} \ge \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
Hence, $$F \ge \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\frac{x}{1-x^2} - \left(3x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = \frac{(2x+\sqrt 3)(3x-\sqrt 3)^2}{6(1-x^2)} \geqslant 0.$$
So
$$\sum \frac{x}{1-x^2} \geqslant 3(x+y+z)-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\geqslant 3\sqrt{3(xy+yz+zx)} - \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
Equality occur when $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}.$